# Solve ordinary differential equation - stuck at initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have recently been introduced to ODEs. The task is to solve
$tx'=x\ln(\frac{x}{t})$ with $x(1)=1$ and say what is its domain.

Now my attempt was to:

$$
t \frac{dx}{dt}=x\ln(\frac{x}{t})
$$

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x}{t}\ln(\frac{x}{t})
$$

substitute $u = \frac{x}{t}$

$$
\frac{du}{t dt} = u \ln u \implies t dt = \frac{du}{u \ln u}
$$
integrate both sides
$$
\frac{t^2}{2}+c=\ln \ln u
$$
exponentiate twice and undo substitution

$$
te^{e^{\frac{t^2}{2}+c}} = x
$$
If I plug in the initial condition x(1) = 1 I get
$$
e^{e^{\frac{1}{2}+c}} = 1
$$
$$
e^{\frac{1}{2}+c} = 0
$$
which is unsolvable! Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in solving the equation after considering $x=ut$ and substituting it. You should get,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(ut)&=u+t\frac{du}{dt}=u\ ln(u)\\
\implies dt/t&=\frac{du}{u(ln(u)-1)}
\end{align}
Substituting $y=ln(u)$, $du/u=dy$ and the equation reduces to:
\begin{align}\frac{dt}{t}&=\frac{dy}{y-1}\\
\implies |t|&=k|y-1|\end{align}
Here, $k=e^c$, where $c$ is the constant of integration obtained after solving the reduced equation.
Your final solution to the equation should then look like this, after substituting back values of $y$ and $u$:
$$t=k\left[ln\frac{x}{t}-1\right],$$
defined for $t>0$ and $x>0$, as per constraints due to the domain of the $ln$ function.
This will satisfy the initial condition mentioned in your question.

Comment: What is $k$ in your equations and where did integral constant go?

Comment: I have edited my original answer. Please check for changes.

Comment: $t=e^c(\ln(\frac{x}{t})-1)$. Multiply that by $e^{-c}$ to get $te^{-c}+1=\ln \frac{x}{t}$. Exponentiate again $te^{te^{-c}+1} = x$ and plug in $x = 1, t=1$ to get $1 = e^{e^{-c}+1}$. Logarithm that and obtain $0 = e^{-c}+1$ which is again unsolvable..

Comment: There is no mistake in solving the equation, according to my knowledge. There is a problem with the initial condition then because no such value of $c$ exists. Check the initial condition once.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{d x(t)}{dt} = \frac{x(t)}{t} \ln \frac{x(t)}{t}$, where we introduce $u(t) = \frac{x(t)}{t}$, hence we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{ d u(t)}{dt} = \frac{ d}{dt} \frac{x(t)}{t} = \frac{1}{t}\frac{dx(t)}{dt} + x(t) \frac{d\frac{1}{t}}{dt}
\end{align*}
where we use the chain rule in the last equality.
So we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{ d u(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{t}u(t) \ln u(t) - \frac{x(t)}{t^2} = \frac{1}{t} \left( u(t) \ln u(t) - u(t) \right).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$t \frac{dx}{dt}=x\ln(\frac{x}{t})$$
I suppose $x>0,t >0$
$$t{dx}-(x\ln(\frac{x}{t}))dt=0$$
$${d\ln x}-(\ln x -\ln t)d\ln t=0$$
$${d\ln x}-\ln x d \ln t =-\ln td\ln t$$
Multiply by $1/t$:
$$d\dfrac {\ln x}t  =-\dfrac {\ln t}{t}d\ln t$$
Integrate:
$$\dfrac {\ln x}t =-\int \frac {\ln t}{t^2}d t+C$$
$$\dfrac {\ln x}t =\frac {\ln t}{t}+\dfrac 1 t+C$$
Initial condition gives $C=-1$
$$\ln x ={\ln t}+1-t$$
Finally:
$$ \boxed {x(t) =te^{1-t}}$$